# Short open tags in PHP are being changed into html comment tag

Tags: php, plesk, php-5.3, legacy

I have a legacy PHP application that was built on codeigniter and still runs PHP5.3 on a server managed using PLESK. It was recently migrated to another server with the same environment.

However, in some parts of my view files, the PHP short open tag `<?=` was changed into `<!--?=`

[image: source code on the left, output on the right]

I want to find out what is doing this in order to have it disabled.

Comment: php doesnt change things. It appears to be some editor that doesn't recognize the code and is converting it to a comment

Comment: View the actual page source instead of using your browser's DOM inspector. I suspect you will just see the PHP source code which means PHP is not being interpreted in your new server

Comment: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213413069-Migrated-websites-that-worked-on-PHP-5-3-are-displayed-incorrectly

Comment: @Phil You were right, "view source" shows the actual raw PHP code, it was just the dev tools making it appear as if the code was changed.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to change `short_open_tag` in your php.ini file.

**If you don't have access to your config file, then you need to enable it through your admin interface...**

I'm not sure about PLESK, but in cPanel, you'd go to:

```
cPanel > Software > Select PHP Versions
```

From the "php options" page, you will see an option for `short_open_tag` near the bottom of the options - change this to `On`.

[image]

Comment: `<?= ` is always available: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @catcon no it is not. the docs link you shared, second paragraph explicitly says the following:
"PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive...)."

Comment: the `<?` can be disabled but not the `<?=`, read the changelog

Comment: my bad, OP use PHP 5.3, `<?=` could be disabled back then